# Android databinding to render a collection

Tags: android, data-binding, observable

Using android databinding (http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) I want to render a collection. How to iterate the collection and render a part of layout multiple times based on the collection data?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at "Advanced Binding" section, under the same link (http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html)

There is a part regarding RecyclerView:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(BindingHolder holder, int position) {
   final T item = mItems.get(position);
   holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.item, item);
   holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
}
```

Comment: There is an object employee with a List of reportees. There is a specific layout to render reportees. The requirement is when I databind employee object, I want the reportees list to be inflated and databinded ie., for list datafields databind should takecare of iteration

Comment: well, you have to use ListView or RecyclerView to do that and implement corresponding adapters for them,